# Abstract function return type in typescript

Tags: typescript

It seems that defining an abstract function with generic return type is not possible with typescript (I am using ts 3.2.4) or I am missing something.

For instance:

```
abstract class Foo {
    abstract func<T>() : T;
}

class Bazz extends Foo {
    func() { return 1; }
}
```

will give an error:

> TS2416: Property 'func' in type 'Bazz' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Foo'.
>     Type '() => number' is not assignable to type '() => T'.
>       Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'.

So, is it possible to define an abstract function that will have the generic return type?

**Edit:**

So, it turns out that using unknown work as expected and it can be used as the return type in an abstract function. But, let's consider this:

```
abstract class Foo{
    getFuncResult() {
        return this.func();
    }
    abstract func() : unknown;
}

class Bazz extends Foo {
    func() { return 1; }
}

let foo: Foo = new Bazz();
foo.func(); // unknown

let bazz = new Bazz() 
bazz.func() // number
bazz.getFuncResult() // unknown
```

I would expect that the getFuncResult on the Bazz will have the same type signature as derived func (number). So, this is more a question about type inference for Typescript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is where you put the type parameter. If the type parameter is on the method, then that method must be generic in derived class. The contract that is specified by that method means we must always be able to call it with any `T` (ie the caller decides with what `T` to call). So this code need to work:

```
let a: Foo = new Bazz()
a.fun<string>() // method is generic caller decides `T`
```

You want to place the type parameter on the class, and fix the type parameter when inheriting in Bazz

```
abstract class Foo <T>{
    abstract func() : T;
}

class Bazz extends Foo<number> {
    func() { return 1; }
}

let foo: Foo<number> = new Bazz();
foo.func(); //ok result is numebr

let fooStr: Foo<string> = new Bazz() // error, different T
```

**Edit**

If you don't care what the return type is in the base class and you just want the derived class to create the method, you could use `unknown` as the return type. If you have a reference to the abstract class and invoke the method it will return `unknown` if you have a reference to a derived class it will return the apropriate type:

```
abstract class Foo{
    abstract func() : unknown;
}

class Bazz extends Foo {
    func() { return 1; }
}

let foo: Foo = new Bazz();
foo.func(); // unknown

let bazz = new Bazz() 
bazz.func() // number
```

**Edit**

With regard to using `func` in another function and expecting the type of that to be relative to `func` typescript will not help you there, at least not by default. By default `getFuncResult` will be typed with what information is known in the base class. Without using a class type parameter (and I do think you should look into that) a solution is to use a type query on the polymorphic `this` type. This will type the return relative to whatever the current class is but you will need to use a type assertion inside the function to get things to work:

```
abstract class Foo{
    getFuncResult() : ReturnType<this['func']> {
        return this.func() as any;
    }
    abstract func() : unknown;
}

class Bazz extends Foo {
    func() { return 1; }
}

let foo: Foo = new Bazz();
foo.func(); // unknown

let bazz = new Bazz() 
bazz.func() // number
bazz.getFuncResult() // number
```

Comment: I understand, but the point is, I don't want to supply the type parameter on the class level, it must be on the function itself. The example is simple but in my case it is a bit more complex and I really don't care what is the return type of the function in the abstract class but the function must be abstract and I do care what is the return type in the inherited class.

Comment: @negyxo Use return of `unknown`  if you don't care about the return ni the base class. I edited the answer to add this option

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but now I realized that my question is not what I wanted to ask. I mean, it is but, it's a bit more complicated. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @negyxo edit nr 2 :) This should work as you want it to, let me know if you need more info

Comment: Yes that's it. I didn't know you can specify like that the return type, I tried with ReturnType<T> but ts complained about unknown function "func". Thanks.

Comment: @negyxo wops I meant `ReturnType<this['func']>` fixed :)

Comment: Now I realized why it didn't work, I marked the func as protected member, in which case ts complained: Type '"func"' cannot be used to index type 'this'
Once again, thanks for the help.

Comment: @negyxo yeah .. for protected members there is not much we can do unfortunately, protected members  do not show up in type queries.

Comment: Amazing answer. `ReturnType<this['func']>` worked great for me